# .Net Dependency Injection Problem: Navigating to pages will always call constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

This ia a WinUI3 application, and it seems that I have proble with dependency injection.

**The problem is that although I try to use `AddScoped` or even `AddSingleton` methods to inject the pages(e.g. `services.AddScoped<MainPage>();`), the constructor of pages will still be called** when calling `frame.Navigate(pageType, parameter)` in class `NavigationService` of file "Navigation.cs" which means that new instances of pages will be created when navigated to this page.
This leads to a serious problem: **every navigation action will call the constructor of pages**, and under "Debug" mode, the "Process Memory" in "Diagnostic Tools" will increase continuously. (And those memory even won't be reclaimed when calling `_frame.GoBack();` in class `NavigationService`)
I try to clean the BackStack of Frame control(`frame.BackStack.Clear();`) or inject the pages with "AddSingleton"(e.g. `services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();`), but the constructor of pages will still be called, leading process memory increaing without stopping.

Here is the "App.xaml.cs", where I inject all the pages, services and so on.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IHost Host { get; }

    public static T GetService<T>() where T : class { return service;}

    public static WindowEx MainWindow { get; } = new MainWindow();

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.
        CreateDefaultBuilder().
        UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory).
        ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            // Default Activation Handler
            services.AddSingleton<ActivationHandler<LaunchActivatedEventArgs>, DefaultActivationHandler>();

            // Services
            services.AddSingleton<ILocalSettingsService, LocalSettingsService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IThemeSelectorService, ThemeSelectorService>();
            services.AddSingleton<INavigationViewService, NavigationViewService>();

            services.AddSingleton<IActivationService, ActivationService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPageService, PageService>();
            services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

            // Core Services
            services.AddSingleton<ISampleDataService, SampleDataService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IFileService, FileService>();

            // Views and ViewModels
            services.AddScoped<SettingsViewModel>();
            services.AddScoped<SettingsPage>();
            services.AddScoped<ListDetailsViewModel>();
            services.AddScoped<ListDetailsPage>();
            services.AddScoped<MainViewModel>();
            services.AddScoped<MainPage>();
            services.AddScoped<ShellPage>();
            services.AddScoped<ShellViewModel>();

            // Configuration
            services.Configure<LocalSettingsOptions>(context.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(LocalSettingsOptions)));
        }).
        Build();
    }

    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnLaunched(args);
        await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the "Navigation.cs", including class `NavigationService` and navigation methods `NavigateTo`， `GoBack()` and others.

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    private readonly IPageService _pageService;
    private Frame? _frame;

     // here is Frame control
    public Frame? Frame { get; set; }

    public NavigationService(IPageService pageService) { _pageService = pageService; }

    public bool GoBack()
    {
        var vmBeforeNavigation = _frame.GetPageViewModel();
        _frame.GoBack();
        if (vmBeforeNavigation is INavigationAware navigationAware)
        {
            navigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom();
        }

        return true;
    }

    // will be called before navigated to one page
    public bool NavigateTo(string pageKey, object? parameter = null, bool clearNavigation = false)
    {
        // get the type of page according to the type of its view model
        // e.g. pageKey = typeof(MainViewModel).FullName
        // then pageType = typeof(MainPage)
        var pageType = _pageService.GetPageType(pageKey);

        if (_frame != null && (_frame.Content?.GetType() != pageType)
        {
            _frame.Tag = clearNavigation;
            var vmBeforeNavigation = _frame.GetPageViewModel();
            
            // navigate to one page
            // every time calling this page, the instance of one page will always be created. Why?
            var navigated = _frame.Navigate(pageType, parameter);
            return navigated;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // will be called after navigated to one page
    private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (sender is Frame frame)
        {
            // force to clear the BackStack of frame
            frame.BackStack.Clear();

            if (frame.GetPageViewModel() is INavigationAware navigationAware)
            {
                navigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(e.Parameter);
            }

            Navigated?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the "MainPage.cs", including class `MainPage`.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    // the constructor of "MainPage" will be called when navigated to MainPage
    public MainPage()
    {
        // the constructor of "MainViewModel" won't be called when navigated to MainPage
        ViewModel = App.GetService<MainViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I started developing .Net not long ago and I really could't find a solution.
How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: The garbage collector eventually will clean up your mess - regardless. However during Debug phase you don't want the GC to be overactive - since you might need those values. So why are you already worried (NOW) about not reclaiming memory - I haven't really looked at your startup routine (glanced over it - seemed ok-ish) tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a single instance of a page, you probably want the Singleton scope. I can't find the docs link, but I believe that a "Scoped" resource is tied to the lifetime of the window within which it is created.

If you're deleting the pages from the navigation stack (which is what Clear() will do) then it will need to be recreated when you navigate to it again.

If you only want a single instance of a page, you should probably look at Page.NavigationCacheMode(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode?view=winrt-22621).

You also need to consider the user experience of only having a single instance of each page and how it is presented to users as they navigate the app. Depending on what your app does, it may or may not be expected that the same instance is shown each time they try and navigate to a "new" page.

Comment: Singleton for each page means single instance no matter the scope - you do realize this?

Comment: In my application, I just want all pages just to be created once because I already have codes to handle every navigation action.  I want to save process memory. (I have one pages with many images, and creating new instances seems to be disaster. )